# Create a histogram of specific columns and rows from a `data.frame` in R

Tags: r, data-science

```
## my data frame 
crime = read.csv("url")

## specific columns that need to be represented
property_crime = crime$Burglary + crime$Theft + crime$`Motor Vehical Theft`

## the rows that I am looking for have the name "harris" within the column named "county_name"

## my attempt
with(crime, hist(harris))


## Error in hist(harris) : object 'harris' not found
```

Not sure why I am getting `object 'harris' not found` as that is the name under the `county_name` column. I'm new to `R`, could someone walk me through the process of displaying a histogram only including the values of specific columns and specific rows?

Comment: Please share your data with `dput()`

Comment: Do you want the unorganized output that is pasted into the console after using dput()?

Comment: @LoganWhitehair Yes, please paste the results of `dput(crime)`

Comment: I am unable to edit my question w/ the contents of dput(crime) as it exceeds the 30000 character limit

Comment: @LoganWhitehair How about `dput(crime[1:50, ])` ?? Do you have any instance of `county_name == "harris"` in the first 50 rows? Also, did my answer get you closer to what you need?

Comment: Sorry guys I'm not sure that I understand R's syntax well enough to ask a good question, I will see my professor in a few hours and will  either check back in if I can articulate a better question or post a solution if I arrive at one, thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

> the rows that I am looking for have the name "harris" within the column named "county_name"

You have to tell `R` the same logic that you are telling us.

There are several ways of making this in `R` but I am going to put here the `base R` way.

We can access the desired rows of object `crime` column `county_name` by indexing like `data.frame[rows, columns]`. So, in your case, `crime[harris_rows, "county_name"]` should work. To get `harris_rows`, we can make a `boolean` index like so `crime$county_name == harris`. If we put all of this together and call `hist()`:

```
hist(crime[crime$county_name == "harris", "county_name"])
```

You don't provide a reproducible example, but you can check a similar logic with the `mtcars` dataset. Here, I am making the histogram of the cars with `mpg > 15`

```
hist(mtcars[mtcars$mpg >15, "mpg"])
# this is another option that produces the same result
# hist(mtcars$mpg[mtcars$mpg >15])
```

Comment: Would it be best practice to add - crime[harris_rows, "county_name"] to a variable and add the columns that I want to include into another variable. Then call hist() with the variables defined earlier, as parameters?

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about best practices at this level of your R journey, but you can certainly create a variable and then pass it as index.

Comment: Thanks for your help, you helped me improve my logical understanding of my problem, however, I don't believe that I understand R's syntax enough to ask anymore good questions to arrive at an answer. I will update if I either find a solution or can think of a better question.